# How to create a Type from an Array in typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I was looking a for a way to convert an array with important values to a **`type`**. I tried with enums and other structures, but for this case was really important to achieve it using **`type`**

constants.ts

```
const validFields = ['ID_PRODUCT', 'PRICE'];

// here should be validFields value as a type
type columns = 'ID_PRODUCT' | 'PRICE' // This is wrong, I don't want to rewrite the code
```

modeling.ts

```
function getBy(query: { column: columns, value: string }) {....}
```

consumer.ts

```
// it will only accept values from the original validFields array
const product = getBy({ column: 'ID_PRODUCT', value: 123 })
```

Is there a way to create something similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way:

constants.ts

```
export const validFields = ['ID_PRODUCTO', 'ID_PADRE'] as const;

export type columns = typeof validFields[number]
```

[credits to this Article](https://steveholgado.com/typescript-types-from-arrays/) by Steve Holgado

It works as expected:

solution:
[image: solution]
recognize the type:
[image: recognize]
is strict with the method:
[image: strict]
autocompletes:
[image: autocomplete]

and it's cleanly transpiled:
[image: ts]